# Not able to get record Id on a app page using lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

I need to show the record name and some custom fields on the record detail page in 3 columns as shown below so I can not use the standard layout. [image]

Temporarily I have achieved it using VF page but now I need to change it to lightning. I am facing issues for creating a lightning component looking as the shown picture.

The lightning component works on the desktop layout but not visible on the mobile layout.

Because of which I tried to use the lightning component on the app page, but on the app page, I am not able to get the record Id.

1. I am not able to show the lightning component on record detail page for mobile.
2. I tried placing the component on the app page, which works but in app page I am not able to get the record Id.

Need help to fix these 2 issues.

Here is my code 
Compenent

```
<aura:component controller="AddLineItemJQgridController" access="global" implements="lightning:actionOverride,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction">

    <aura:attribute name="newOrder" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="simpleNewOrder" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="newOrderError" type="String"/>


    <aura:attribute name="AircoAcc" type="sObject" default="{}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="OtterAcc" type="sObject" default="{}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="IntbAcc" type="sObject" default="{}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="AircoShipAdd" type="sObject" default="{}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="OtterShipAdd" type="sObject" default="{}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="IntbShipAdd" type="sObject" default="{}"/>

    <aura:attribute name="AircoAccount" type="Pronto_Customer__c" />
    <aura:attribute name="OtterAccount" type="account" />
    <aura:attribute name="InterbathAccount" type="account" />

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

    <force:recordData aura:id="orderRecordCreator"  layoutType="FULL" targetRecord="{!v.newOrder}" targetFields="{!v.simpleNewOrder}" targetError="{!v.newOrderError}"  recordId="{!v.recordId}" />

    <!-- Display the new contact form -->
    <div class="Create Order">
        <lightning:card iconName="action:new_contact" title="Create Order">
            <lightning:layout multipleRows="true"> 
                <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" size="12"> 
                    <dl class="slds-dl_horizontal">
                        <dt class="slds-dl_horizontal__label">
                            <c:customLookup  objectAPIName="Pronto_Customer__c" IconName="standard:account" selectedRecord="{!v.AircoAcc}" label="Airco Customer"/>
                        </dt>
                        <dd  class="slds-dl_horizontal__label">
                            <c:customLookup objectAPIName="account" IconName="standard:account" selectedRecord="{!v.OtterAcc}" label="Otter Customer"  />
                        </dd >
                        <dd  class="slds-dl_horizontal__label">
                            <c:customLookup objectAPIName="account" IconName="standard:account" selectedRecord="{!v.IntbAcc}" label="Interbath Customer"  />
                        </dd >
                    </dl>
                    <br/><br/>
                    <dl class="slds-dl_horizontal">
                        <dt class="slds-dl_horizontal__label">
                            <p>Delivery Address: {!v.AircoAcc.Delivery_Address__c}</p>
                        </dt>
                        <dt class="slds-dl_horizontal__label">
                            <p>Delivery Address: {!v.OtterAcc.Delivery_Address__c}</p>                    
                        </dt>
                        <dt class="slds-dl_horizontal__label">
                            <p>Delivery Address: {!v.IntbAcc.Delivery_Address__c}</p>                   
                        </dt>
                    </dl>
                    <br/><br/>
                    <dl class="slds-dl_horizontal">
                        <dt class="slds-dl_horizontal__label">
                            <lightning:input type="checkbox" aura:id="orderField" label="Same As Account Address" value="{!v.simpleNewOrder.Same_as_Store_Address_Airco__c}"/>
                        </dt>
                        <dt class="slds-dl_horizontal__label">
                            <lightning:input type="checkbox" aura:id="orderField" label="Same As Account Address" value="{!v.simpleNewOrder.Same_as_Stored_Address__c}"/>
                        </dt>
                        <dt class="slds-dl_horizontal__label">
                            <lightning:input type="checkbox" aura:id="orderField" label="Same As Account Address" value="{!v.simpleNewOrder.Same_as_Stored_Address__c}"/>
                        </dt>
                    </dl>
                    <br/><br/>
                    <dl class="slds-dl_horizontal">
                        <dt class="slds-dl_horizontal__label">
                            <c:customLookup aura:id="orderField" objectAPIName="Otter_FFA_Shipping_Address__c" IconName="standard:account" selectedRecord="{!v.AircoShipAdd}" label="Alternate Airco Shipping Address"  />
                        </dt>
                        <dt class="slds-dl_horizontal__label">
                            <c:customLookup aura:id="orderField" objectAPIName="Otter_FFA_Shipping_Address__c" IconName="standard:account" selectedRecord="{!v.OtterShipAdd}" label="Alternate Otter Shipping Address"  />
                        </dt>
                        <dt class="slds-dl_horizontal__label">
                            <c:customLookup aura:id="orderField" objectAPIName="Otter_FFA_Shipping_Address__c" IconName="standard:account" selectedRecord="{!v.IntbShipAdd}" label="Alternate Interbath Shipping Address"  />
                        </dt>
                    </dl>
                    <br/><br/>
                    <dl class="slds-dl_horizontal">
                        <dt class="slds-dl_horizontal__label">
                            <lightning:input aura:id="orderField" label="Purchase Order" value="{!v.simpleNewOrder.Otter_FFA_Purchase_Order__c}"/>
                        </dt>
                        <dt class="slds-dl_horizontal__label">
                            <lightning:input type="date" aura:id="orderField" label="Required Date" value="{!v.simpleNewOrder.Required_Date__c}"/>
                        </dt>
                        <dt class="slds-dl_horizontal__label">
                            <lightning:input  aura:id="orderField" label="Remarks" value="{!v.simpleNewOrder.Otter_FFA_Remarks__c}"/>
                        </dt>
                    </dl>
                </lightning:layoutItem>
            </lightning:layout>
            <lightning:button label="Save Order" variant="brand" onclick="{!c.handleSaveOrder}"/>
        </lightning:card>
    </div>

    <!-- Display Lightning Data Service errors -->
    <aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.newOrderError))}">
        <div class="recordError">
            {!v.newOrderError}</div>
    </aura:if>

</aura:component>


Controller
`({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        // Prepare a new record from template
        component.find("orderRecordCreator").getNewRecord(
            "Order__c", // sObject type (objectApiName)
            null,      // recordTypeId
            false,     // skip cache?
            $A.getCallback(function() {
                var rec = component.get("v.newOrder");
                var error = component.get("v.newOrderError");
                if(error || (rec === null)) {
                    console.log("Error initializing record template: " + error);
                    return;
                }
                console.log("Record template initialized: " + rec.apiName);
            })
        );
    },

    handleSaveOrder: function(component, event, helper) {
        var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
        createRecordEvent.setParams({
            "entityApiName": "Order__c",
            'defaultFieldValues': {
                'Otter_FFA_Purchase_Order__c' : component.get("v.simpleNewOrder.Otter_FFA_Purchase_Order__c"),
                'Required_Date__c' : component.get("v.simpleNewOrder.Required_Date__c"),
                'Otter_FFA_Remarks__c' : component.get("v.simpleNewOrder.Otter_FFA_Remarks__c"),
                'Otter_FFA_Remarks__c' : component.get("v.simpleNewOrder.Same_as_Store_Address_Airco__c")
            }
        });
        createRecordEvent.fire();
      }
})`
```

Comment: Have you tired [lightning:recordViewForm](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordViewForm/specification)?

Comment: Also can you add code snippet? Usually you have to implement an interface called as [hasRecordId](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:hasRecordId/documentation)

Comment: Since you are already implementing the relevant interfaces, you'll probably need to add more detail about the specific issue you see and what the problem is.

Comment: The problem is that I can see the lightning component on my desktop view but not on mobile view because of which I tried to use app page instead of record detail page. But in app page I am not able to get the record Id.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For this I created a complete separate function only for the mobile as nothing else was working

Comment: Can you add a little detail to this? As it stands it won't be of much use to anyone else who comes across this and has a similar problem later on.